# How to include functions with auto return type from header file into multiple cpp files

Tags: c++, lambda, header, auto, include-guards

I want to define a function of auto return type in such a way, that I can call it from multiple .cpp files if I include the header.  I have 4 files

`head.hpp` - where the function is

```cpp
#ifndef HEAD_HPP
#define HEAD_HPP 

auto f();

#endif
```

`head.cpp` - where the function is declared

```cpp
#include "head.hpp"

auto f(){
    return [](){
        return 10;
    };
}
```

`test1.cpp` - where it is used

```cpp
#include "head.hpp"
int foo(){
    auto func = f();
    return f();
}
```

`main.cpp` - where it is used as well

```cpp
#include "head.hpp"
int foo();
int main(){
    auto fu = f();

    return fu() + 5 + foo();
}
```

All files are **compiled together**
I still get the error:

> error: use of ‘auto f()’ before deduction of ‘auto’

> auto fu = f();

Comment: Remember the [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) (One Definition Rule).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way.

When you call a function in C++:

```
auto fu=f();
```

The compiler must know the discrete type that the function actually returns. `auto` is not a real type. It is just a placeholder for a type to be figured out later.

But this "later" never comes. If all that the compiler sees is an `auto` return type, the compiler cannot determine the function's actual return type, and, therefore, the program is ill-formed, and you get a compilation error.

This is a fundamental aspect to C++, and there are no workarounds.

Comment: so to use the function in multiple files, i have to manually redeclare it in each one?

Comment: No, you need to declare what the function actually returns in the header file. In C++, every function always returns the same type, always. Declare it as such in the header file. This one returns a lambda that takes no parameters and returns an `int`. In this case, declaring `std::function<int ()> f()` in the header file (including `<functional>`, of course, and defining the same in its `.cpp` file), should be sufficient. Also, in this very specific case returning a plain function pointer will also work, too.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out what the function declaration for this lambda is:
`auto f2= [&drv]<typename T>(T expected)->void`

Comment: This does not appear to be a lambda, but a template. A completely different story, because [templates can only be implemented in header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). If you do not understand that, you should ask a new question, and follow the instructions for creating a [mre], as explained in the [help]. See [ask] for more directions.